# Install frameworks in IDE or system wide?

Tags: linux, visual-studio-code, terminal, pycharm, virtualenv

When installing Node.JS or PyTorch for example, I can either install those in the regular system wide linux terminal or I can use the PyCharm or VS Code terminal.

With PyCharm from my understanding I can create virtual environments to manage different Python versions. Is it the same in VS Code?

If not, is there a difference between installing Node.JS through VS Code or the system terminal?

Answer (score 0):

A virtual environment is much better, because you have control of the version. It is easy e.g. when you have one version in production, and one in development, and you are try to see if you can upgrade the tools.

Pycharm now is collaborating with Anaconda, to improve integration of the two tools, so with conda environment you can have not only python virtual environment, but npm and other non python programs/utilities.

The disadvantage: some more command to learn (and it is more complex), but you will make mistakes, with virtual environment you just remove such environment and you start again. On system it is more difficult to know what you installed, what was on base system etc

Answer (score 0):

All the options have their pros and cons.

Installing anything by an IDE would make your development dependant on that IDE. Furthermore, you lose the options to learn the package management of the software what you use.

Learning `npm` or `pip` is really not a serious thing, the IDE shortcuts are for really beginners on this sense.

However, in many cases they may make your IDE to "know" about the packages better.

I would strongly disagree to install anything system-wide. They can have unwaited interactions with your system.

Best if you install them as user, into your home, but independently from your IDE. However, this requires the most learning.